# Concrete type vs Not concrete type in Golang

Tags: go, design-patterns

Concrete type vs Not concrete type.
What is the distinct difference between the concrete type and not concrete type in Golang and how do you decide which one to use ?
here's a sample code:

```
type Animal1 interface{
    speak()
}

type Animal2 interface{
    speak() string
}
```

1. Does the absence of type in Animal1 interface method `speak()` makes it a not concrete type?
2. How do you decide when to use either concrete or none concrete type ?

Comment: What is a "concrete type"? The word "concrete" doesn't occur in Go's language spec.

Answer (score 4):

A concrete type is a data type that is not an interface. In your example, both types are interfaces. The first one has a `speak` method that does not return anything. The second one has a `speak` method that returns a string.